# promise inside cron only executes once

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm really stuck here.  Promises, by definition, only return once.  However, I need to figure out a way to get promises working with the cron module.  Below is a shortened version of what I'm trying to do.  Everything executes just fine the first time but after that the promise never resolves.

Unfortunately I'm stuck using the node-pool module which is where the promise comes from.  This module is required for connection pooling with HANA databases.

Thanks!

```
var pool = require('generic-pool');
var servers = require('../config/servers');
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var hdb = require('hdb'); // database driver
var factories = {};
var pools = {};

for (let i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {

    factories[servers[i].name] = {

        create: function(){
             return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                var client = hdb.createClient({
                    host: servers[i].host,
                    port: servers[i].port,
                    user: servers[i].user,
                    password: servers[i].password
                });

                resolve(client);

            });
        },
        destroy: function(client){
            if (!client.hadError && client.readyState !== 'closed') {
                client.end();
            }
        }

    };

    pools[servers[i].name] = pool.createPool(factories[servers[i].name]);

}


var job = new CronJob({

    cronTime: '0 * * * *',
    onTick: () => {

        async.waterfall([

            (callbackWF) => {

                var resourcePromise = pools[name].acquire();

                console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS - ') + 'Attempting to resolve promise for Name: ' + name + ' Table: ' + table);

                resourcePromise.then( (client) => {

                    console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS - ') + 'Got promise for Name: ' + name + ' Table: ' + table);

                    if (client.readyState != 'connected') {

                        client.connect( (err) => {

                            if (err) {

                                console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS - ') + 'Error while connecting to client. Name: ' + name + ' Host: ' + host + ' Port: ' + port + ' User: ' + user + ' Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));

                                return callbackWF('error', client);

                            } 

                            callbackWF(null, client);

                        });

                    } else {

                        callbackWF(null, client);

                    }

                }).catch( (err) => {

                    if (err) {

                        console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS - ') + 'Error getting promise for connection pool. Name: ' + name + ' Host: ' + host + ' Port: ' + port + ' User: ' + user + ' Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                        callbackWF('error');

                    }

                    console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS - ') + 'Caught promise');

                });


            },

            // Get data for table.
            (client, callbackWF) => {

                client.exec(select, {rowsAsArray: true}, (err, rows) => {

                    if (err) {

                        console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS - ') + 'Error while getting data from ' + name +  " table: " + table + ". " + err + select);
                        return callbackWF(err, client);

                    }

                    callbackWF(null, client);

                });

            }

        ], (err, client) => {

            if (typeof client != 'undefined') {

                console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS - ') + 'Releasing pool for Name: ' + name + ' Table: ' + table);

                pools[name].release(client);

            }

        });

    },
    start: true,
    timeZone: 'UTC'
});
```

Comment: "*…after that the promise never resolves*" means that it's a new promise, since the one from the first time was fulfilled just fine. There is nothing wrong in the code you have shown us, the problem is within `acquire`. Please post that.

Comment: Are you sure that you did call `pool.release()` somewhere? Otherwise it's quite logical that the next `acquire` never resolves

Comment: in the 'do stuff' block, its a async.waterfall function.  The 'done' of the waterfall is `pools[name].release(client);`  Is there more debugging I should be doing with the status of the pools?

Comment: Using `async.waterfall` together with promises is most likely your problem. Yes, please try debugging this (at least make sure the problem is really the `release` not happening by simply adding a `console.log` next to it and checking whether it runs), or post the full code so that we might advise on it.

Comment: Code updated! Thanks for taking a look

Comment: So, is `release` called as expected or not? Could you post the log output?

Comment: Ah crap, I got it.  There was a return in one of the if statements that prevented the waterfall callback.  Doh.  I'm probably going to put a timeout to automatically call the callback now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with this. A promise might only return once, but you can totally call `then()` on it as many times as you want.